# How to identify element by text when text is spanned over multiple lines using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

Is it possible to write xpath using contains text such as(Below is what I want but does not work)

```
//ul[@role='listbox']/..//span[contains(text(),'Fast-Food Restaurent')]
```

**Page Code:**

```
<span class="item-title" md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="i">Fast-<span class="highlight">Food</span> Restaurant</span>
```

It is an auto complete text box when I enter the word food, there are some options and I want to select Fast-Food Restaurant from it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the element you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using the texts *Food* and *Fast*:

  ```
  //ul[@role='listbox']/..//span[.//span[text()='Food']][contains(.,'Fast-')]
  ```
- Using the texts *Food* and *Restaurant*:

  ```
  //ul[@role='listbox']/..//span[.//span[text()='Food']][contains(.,'Restaurant')]
  ```
- Using the texts *Food*, *Fast* and *Restaurant*:

  ```
  //ul[@role='listbox']/..//span[.//span[text()='Food']][contains(.,'Fast-') and contains(.,'Restaurant')]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can amend your path to the following:

```
//ul[@role='listbox']/..//span[contains(normalize-space(), 'Fast-Food Restaurant')]
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can select required `span` node based on its *string representation*:

```
//span[.='Fast-Food Restaurant']
```